# How to specify pluginList as maven dependencies for findbugs-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

I would like to know if there is a way to specify findbugs attribute for plugins, `pluginList` as maven dependencies instead as a file path.

I mean, if I use this configuration:

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
                <pluginList>/my/path/fb-contrib-6.2.3.jar</pluginList>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Findbugs load the plugins jar and analyze the code as I want. But as you can see, jar location is a fixed path. I would like to use something like this:

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <xmlOutputDirectory>target/site</xmlOutputDirectory>
                <pluginList>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.mebigfatguy.fb-contrib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>fb-contrib</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </pluginList>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Obviously, the last configuration does not work, but it is more convenient from a Maven point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it with the `<plugins>` parameter, and not `<pluginList>`.

Quoting [the documentation](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html#Using_Third_party_or_your_own_detectors):

> The `pluginList` option specifies a comma-separated list of optional BugDetector Jar files to add.
>   ...
>   The `plugins` option defines a collection of PluginArtifact to work on.

A sample configuration would be:

```xml
<configuration>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.mebigfatguy.fb-contrib</groupId>
      <artifactId>fb-contrib</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.3</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</configuration>
```